# Codility why NailingPlanks return incorrect result for random small sequence?

Tags: java

I try to solve nailingPlanks example. I made some code (look below) whtich solve almost all test cases except 3. My code return wrong answer but I don't know why.

Codlility says "**WRONG ANSWER got 79 expected 61**" for for **random_small random sequence, length = ~100**

This is this test case:

```
    int[] A = { 28, 18, 43, 15, 26, 18, 21, 49, 6, 23, 12, 18, 50, 17, 31,              21, 37, 23, 9, 22, 21, 40, 29, 10, 34, 15, 26, 11, 21, 40, 26,  38, 38, 30, 33, 20, 31, 39, 5, 47, 19, 7, 8, 18, 4, 20, 21, 33,24, 47, 33, 17, 44, 35, 49, 37, 49, 11, 14, 49, 2, 47, 6, 7,8, 46, 48, 44, 37, 38, 16, 1, 32, 45, 48, 26, 1, 9, 23, 12, 2,10, 25, 7, 6, 9, 2, 40, 44, 11, 32, 44, 13, 17, 45, 39, 32, 40,29, 16 };
    int[] B = { 55, 32, 44, 48, 36, 31, 41, 81, 56, 46, 62, 68, 62, 20,39, 63, 67, 69, 58, 55, 48, 43, 30, 51, 68, 53, 54, 45, 53, 85,  31, 63, 53, 72, 77, 32, 35, 51, 21, 86, 39, 45, 23, 44, 13, 52,47, 76, 72, 73, 36, 64, 92, 59, 73, 84, 61, 24, 49, 83, 36, 89, 72, 28, 19, 56, 66, 66, 74, 69, 42, 20, 63, 64, 88, 58, 36, 28,  49, 48, 50, 36, 41, 42, 12, 26, 3, 68, 56, 30, 72, 76, 14, 39,45, 80, 57, 83, 42, 57 };
    int[] C = { 55, 35, 85, 29, 52, 35, 42, 98, 11, 45, 23, 35, 100, 33,61, 42, 74, 45, 18, 44, 41, 80, 57, 20, 68, 30, 52, 22, 42, 79, 52, 76, 76, 59, 65, 40, 62, 78, 10, 94, 37, 14, 16, 35, 7, 40,42, 66, 47, 94, 66, 33, 88, 70, 97, 74, 97, 21, 28, 98, 3, 93,92, 14, 16, 92, 96, 87, 73, 76, 31, 1, 63, 89, 95, 52, 1, 18,45, 24, 3, 20, 50, 13, 12, 17, 4, 79, 87, 21, 64, 88, 25, 34,89, 77, 63, 80, 58, 32, 69, 79, 6, 33, 30, 89, 29, 68, 44, 38,            50, 90, 66, 39, 16, 35, 48, 65, 100, 33, 95, 92, 45, 23, 24,93, 18, 65, 66, 17, 4, 64, 6, 55, 98, 47, 32, 11, 31, 33, 12,   71, 61, 72, 11, 26, 93, 1, 37, 82, 23, 23, 64, 26, 34, 40,30,   66, 74, 77, 99, 8, 26, 99, 80, 77, 23, 13, 28, 90, 76, 37, 66,74, 29, 11, 82, 71, 81, 75, 37, 66, 37, 91, 13, 70, 35, 91, 81,18, 2, 24, 97, 77, 71, 21, 22, 45, 54, 62, 6, 85, 25, 72, 32,30, 88, 22, 51, 88, 83, 72, 25, 63, 48, 31, 78, 68, 90, 43, 15,28, 74, 71, 65, 40, 58, 7, 10, 81, 12, 63, 30, 18, 79, 89, 32,16, 47, 12, 97, 3, 51, 17, 1, 100, 69, 71, 77, 79, 61, 67, 32,   11, 73, 74, 74, 65, 9, 65, 9, 88, 1, 27, 54, 87, 66, 14, 73,21, 34, 37, 80, 21, 33, 29, 25, 22, 39, 18, 26, 12, 59, 70, 24, 45, 61, 98, 97, 12, 95, 81, 23, 20, 51, 29, 32, 41, 55, 55 };
```

my code:

```
import java.util.Arrays;

class Solution {
    public static class Nail implements Comparable<Nail> {
        int value = -1;
        int orginalIndex = -2;

        public Nail(int val, int idx) {
            value = val;
            orginalIndex = idx;
        }
    @Override
    public int compareTo(Nail o) {
        int dv = value - o.value;
        return dv;
    }
}

public static final Nail INCORECT_NAIL = new Nail(-1, -2);

public int solution(int[] A, int[] B, int[] C) {

    int N = A.length;
    int M = C.length;

    Nail[] nails = new Nail[M];
    for (int i = 0; i < C.length; i++) {
        nails[i] = new Nail(C[i], i);
    }
    Nail[] sortedNails = Arrays.copyOf(nails, nails.length);
    Arrays.sort(sortedNails);

    int solution = -1;
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {

        solution = binSearch(sortedNails, A[i], B[i], solution);
        if (solution == -1)
            return -1;
    }

    return solution + 1;

}

int binSearch(Nail[] sortedNails, int beginPlank, int endPlank, int solution) {

    int M = sortedNails.length;

    // jeżeli wszystkie gwoździe są poza deską to nie ma rozwiązania
    if (sortedNails[sortedNails.length - 1].value < beginPlank)
        return -1;
    if (sortedNails[0].value > endPlank)
        return -1;

    int aidx = Arrays.binarySearch(sortedNails, new Nail(beginPlank,
            beginPlank));
    int bidx = Arrays.binarySearch(sortedNails,
            new Nail(endPlank, endPlank));

    int a = (aidx >= 0 ? aidx : -aidx - 1);
    int b = (bidx >= 0 ? bidx : -bidx - 2);

    if (b < a)
        return -1;
    // System.out.println(a +" - " + b);
    if (sortedNails[a].value > endPlank)
        return -1;
    if (sortedNails[b].value < beginPlank)
        return -1;

    int minOrginalIndex = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    Nail currentNail = null;
    while (a < M && (sortedNails[a].value <= endPlank)) {
        currentNail = sortedNails[a];
        if (currentNail.orginalIndex <= solution) {
            return solution;
        }
        if (currentNail.orginalIndex < minOrginalIndex) {
            minOrginalIndex = currentNail.orginalIndex;
        }
        a++;
    }
    //System.out.print(minOrginalIndex + " | ");
    return minOrginalIndex;

}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java binarySearch method is [documented](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#binarySearch%28java.lang.Object%5B%5D,%20java.lang.Object%29) as "If the array contains multiple elements equal to the specified object, there is no guarantee which one will be found".

In order for your algorithm to work, you need to find the first nail that nails each plank so you know you will look at all of them.